# Best way to implement horizontal scrolling list type view in Android

Tags: android, list, view, horizontal-scrolling

I need to create a horizontal list type view which shows a number of views are simply an image and a small piece of text. The list needs be flickable with inertial scrolling, have recycling of views and needs to be able to lazy load the views when they're viewable or just outside range of what's 
viewable.

Here's what I've considered and why they dont seem suitable.

Gallery - Deprecated so can't use.

ViewPager - Doesn't allow you to flick the through the pages, a flick simply moves to the next page.

HorizontalScrollView - Need to add the views to it manually rather than using an adapter to provide the required view so views aren't recycled or lazy loaded.

I also cant use any libraries or Views created by others to achieve this irrespective of whether their license say they're free to use or not.

Two options come to mind to achieve this. The first is to use HorizontalScrollView and create and add all the child views when setting it up but without their images and then detect when views are almost visible and load their images then. I could still be creating a few hundred views and adding them here in one go but at least I wouldn't be loading all the images into memory. The second option is to write my own AdapterView to do exactly what I want which seems the most flexible but also the most labour intensive.

Any opinions on the best way to achieve this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With HorizontalScrollView you need to manually add the layout.
With my analysis ViewPager is the best controller. You can easily control the postions in viewpager from its adapter.
You can set multiple pages of a viewpager in a single screen by overriding getPageWidth(int position) method of the adapter class. Also you can use onCreateView method of fragment class to re-use the view.

```
@Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          return 0.5f;
    }
```

This will have 2 pages at a time on a single Screen